# ios UINavbar uibarButtonItem set icon/image color (mask)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, masking

I have probably missed a good thread somewhere that tells me what I am doing wrong but this is my problem atm:
I have a UINavbar and a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem.
The png 'trspBlackBtn30' just gives the button a slightly transparent background.
The png 'backArrow' is just a png with a black arrow on transparent background.
I want to do like in css - put like a mask on the 'backArrow' to change its arrow color. So that I dont have to make a new png for each colored arrow.
I have tried this:

```
-(void)customizeAppBtn30{
UIImage *barBtn30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"trspBlackBtn30"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
UIImage *backIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backArrow"];
UIButton *trpBtn30 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

[trpBtn30 setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[trpBtn30 setBackgroundImage:barBtn30 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[trpBtn30 setImage:backIcon forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGPoint bounds = CGPointMake(4, 4);
[trpBtn30 pointInside:bounds withEvent:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *trspBackBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:trpBtn30];
//self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
trspBackBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:trspBackBtn];
```

}

All I get is the stupid black arrow. Help me please

Comment: Do I have an unclear question or am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: I HAVE SOLVED THIS!! yeay

Comment: would you mind reply your question with the solution that has worked for you? thanks ;)